# Como percorrer todos os dados de um DF fazendo cálculo e retorno o valor para o mesmo?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: df]Estou com DF após alguns cálculos, mas não estou conseguindo passar os dados para uma conta, toda vez dá esse erro:

> ```
> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
> ```

Código:

```
#biblilotecas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('Semana.xlsx') #leitura do excel
df1 = pd.read_excel('Semana1.xlsx') #leitura do excel
df2 = pd.read_excel('Semana2.xlsx') #leitura do excel
df3 = pd.read_excel('Semana3.xlsx') #leitura do excel

df = df + df1 + df2 + df3
df = df.T #girando tabela
df = df.drop(['Dia'], axis=0)
df = df.T #girando tabela
df = df // 4
df.columns = ['1', '2' ,'3','4','5','6','7']

Parte da conta: 

Lamb = ' aqui tem que recebe o valor de cada posiçao ' 
u = 7
Caixas = 22

for lamb in lamb:
    while(lamb/(Caixas*u) >= 0.9):
        Caixas += 1

while(lamb/(Caixas*u) <= 0.5):
    Caixas -= 1
else:
    print('Resultados')
    F = lamb/(Caixas*u)
    F = F * 100
    print('==========')
    print(lamb, '/', Caixas,'*',u)
    print('Numero de caixas recomendável e:',Caixas)
    print('Caixas ficam ocupados' ,"%.0f" % F , "%")
```

Comment: você pode dar um exemplo de como estão esses dados? eles têm header? são do mesmo tipo?

Comment: O que é `lamb`? `lamb` e `Lamb` são a mesma coisa ou são variáveis diferentes?

Comment: Cara tem muita coisa errada no teu código, recomendo você voltar um pouco e estudar estrutura de repetição, condicionais, estrutura de dados e assim da prosseguimento a esse projeto

Comment: as lamb estão repetidas por que estava tentando um outro jeito que nao deu certo..

lamb = os valores do DF
u = 7
Caixas = 22

while(lamb/(Caixas*u) >= 0.9):
    print("adição de caixas")
    Caixas += 1
    print(Caixas)
else:
    print("Redução de caixas")
    
while(lamb/(Caixas*u) <= 0.5):
    Caixas -= 1
    print(Caixas)
else:
    print('Resultados')
    F = lamb/(Caixas*u)
    F = F * 100
    print('==========')
    print(lamb, '/', Caixas,'*',u)
    print('Numero de caixas recomendável e:',Caixas)
    print('Caixas ficam ocupados' ,"%.0f" % F , "%")

Comment: Quero que todos os dados do DF passem pela conta, então conta ira retorna um valor e esse valor ficara no DF

Answer (score 1):

Veja se é isso que você deseja, ele remove 30 do valor atual.
O "segredo" está no lambda que você coloca a expresão que quiser ou acesso a uma função com retorno (2º Exemplo).

O "for" acessa coluna a coluna e retorna o valor

```
#Instalar pacote
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

lista_valores = [
                 [74,80,90,0,67,68,73]
                ,[91,88,93,97,71,90,87]
                ,[97,93,102,110,83,97,95]
                ,[110,110,115,154,95,111,101]
                ,[125,144,121,177,97,110,86]
                ]

df = pd.DataFrame(lista_valores, columns = ['1', '2','3','4','5','6','7'])

print('=== Dataframe Original ===')
print(df)
print()

#For das colunas do dataframe
for x in df.columns:
    print('Acessando a coluna:',x)
    #Acessa o campo do dataframe
    #Remover o valor de cada campo
    df[x] = df[x].apply(lambda x: x-30)



print('\n=== Dataframe Alterado coluna a coluna')
print(df)
```

Usando uma função para retornar impar ou par por exemplo.

```
#Instalar pacote
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

lista_valores = [
                 [74,80,90,0,67,68,73]
                ,[91,88,93,97,71,90,87]
                ,[97,93,102,110,83,97,95]
                ,[110,110,115,154,95,111,101]
                ,[125,144,121,177,97,110,86]
                ]

df = pd.DataFrame(lista_valores, columns = ['1', '2','3','4','5','6','7'])

print('=== Dataframe Original ===')
print(df)
print()

def impar_par(valor):
    if(valor%2==0):
        return "par"
    else:
        return "impar"

#For das colunas do dataframe
for x in df.columns:
    print('Acessando a coluna:',x)
    #Acessa o campo do dataframe
    #Remover o valor de cada campo
    df[x] = df[x].apply(lambda x: impar_par(x))



print('\n=== Dataframe Alterado coluna a coluna')
print(df)
```